# configuring app.yaml for redirecting to another PHP files from index.php

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm looking for the way to allow PHP file to redirect to another PHP file in GAE standard(from index.php to news.php,detail.php). I've already done with deploying and can see the index.php(This is a top page) on browser. And when I check this site in my local, It redirect to news.php or detail.php from specific buttons. However, both of them are routed into index.php in GAE. Is there mistake on app.yaml?? Thank you so much.

```
files and folders

app.yaml  composer.json  css  detail.php  img  index.php  js  news.php  thanks.html
```

```
runtime: php72
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|mov))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|mov)$

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /thanks.html
  static_files: thanks.html
  upload: thanks.html

- url: /index/.*
  script: detail.php

- url: /index/.*
  script: news.php

- url: .*
  script: auto

env_variables:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by making controller.php below in same directory as index.php.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){
    require('index.php');
    return;
}

$regex = '/.+\.php/';
if (preg_match($regex, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    $file_path = __DIR__ . $matches[0];
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {
        require($file_path);
        return;
    }
}

http_response_code(404);
exit('Not Found');

?>
```

```
app.yaml

entrypoint: serve controller.php
```